# Ng-map How to get currently opened Infowindow object

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

Using https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps,is there a way to get the google maps infowindow object from the controller? Motivation is to update position of currently opened infowindow (based on an interval) using `infowindow.setPosition` method

Template defined:

```
<info-window id="foo" template="foo.html">
</info-window>
```

Controller:

```
map.showInfoWindow('foo', marker);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I should read docs more, it's `NgMap.getMap().infoWindows`